# What is the location of assembly in <%Register %>

Tags: vb.net, .net-assembly

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="jwg" Namespace="Janus.Web.GridEX" Assembly="Janus.Web.GridEX" %>
```

What would be the physical location of Assembly "Janus.Web.GridEX"... I looked into C:\Window\assembly but I did not find "Janus.Web.GridEX"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assembly is part of the Janus.Web.GridEx library that your project is referencing. The library (DLL) is usually located in the BIN directory of your application.

If this is a 64-bit compatibility issue, try this:
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/55cd5e11-49a9-4158-8b1f-7f2aa4ad2f07.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Yes I have that one in the bin and I have referenced to that. But when I try to run the same project (with same bin and .vbproj) in another machine - I get an error - "An error has occured in the script in this page" And on debugging it on IE debugger at run time I could see that it could not find Janus.Web.GridEx... Thats why I thought assembly might also be looking in GAC or someplace and thats why throwing such an error... Do you have an idea as why is this happening...Thanks...

Comment: Are you sure that the DLL is being carried over? Is it the same version of the DLL? The assembly could have changed between versions.

Comment: I thought of all that too... Copied as it is... the only difference is that it was copied from 32 bit to 64 bit machine and that the IIS versions are different in 2 machines(from version5 to version6)...so could it be some IIS settings issue? But looking at the error, doesnt look like. It clearly says object is null at the line where this namespace tag is used in the aspx page... I dont even know what to do next! dll exists with the same version in 2 machines as it is...

Comment: Or the DLL might not be 64-bit compatible. I've had that happen a number of times.

Comment: Alright. Would need to check on that! This is the first time I am trying this on 64 bit machine. Thanks.

Comment: No I am able to run the asp1.1 on 64 bit alright. Its just about this particular error. Also, I saw that my team had already installed it in one 64 platform with using the same dlls. It must have some other settings realted issue :-(

Answer (score 0):

The assembly will be referenced by the project where this `@ Register` directive is.

Normally it will be copied to the `bin` directory on compilation - if this is a web site (not a web _project), it will have to be.

Answer (score 0):

Open References folder of your project. Find Janus.Web.GridEX.dll. Open its properties and look up the physical path.